# Cannot query example AddressBook protobuf data in hive with elephant-bird

Tags: hadoop, hive, protocol-buffers, elephantbird

I'm trying to use elephant bird to query some example protobuf data.  I'm using the AddressBook example, and I serialized a handful of fake AddressBooks into files and put them in hdfs under /user/foo/data/elephant-bird/addressbooks/  The query returns no results

I setup the table and query like so:

```
add jar /home/foo/downloads/elephant-bird/hadoop-compat/target/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.6-SNAPSHOT.jar;
add jar /home/foo/downloads/elephant-bird/core/target/elephant-bird-core-4.6-SNAPSHOT.jar;
add jar /home/foo/downloads/elephant-bird/hive/target/elephant-bird-hive-4.6-SNAPSHOT.jar;

create external table addresses
row format serde "com.twitter.elephantbird.hive.serde.ProtobufDeserializer"
with serdeproperties (
"serialization.class"="com.twitter.data.proto.tutorial.AddressBookProtos$AddressBook")
STORED AS
-- elephant-bird provides an input format for use with hive
INPUTFORMAT "com.twitter.elephantbird.mapred.input.DeprecatedRawMultiInputFormat"
-- placeholder as we will not be writing to this table
OUTPUTFORMAT "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"
LOCATION '/user/foo/data/elephant-bird/addressbooks/';


describe formatted addresses;

OK
# col_name              data_type               comment

person array{ struct{  name:string, id:int, email:string, phone:array {struct {number:string, type:string}}}}  from deserializer
byteData                binary                  from deserializer

# Detailed Table Information
Database:               default
Owner:                  foo
CreateTime:             Tue Oct 28 13:49:53 PDT 2014
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN
Protect Mode:           None
Retention:              0
Location:               hdfs://foo:8020/user/foo/data/elephant-bird/addressbooks
Table Type:             EXTERNAL_TABLE
Table Parameters:
        EXTERNAL                TRUE
        transient_lastDdlTime   1414529393

# Storage Information
SerDe Library:          com.twitter.elephantbird.hive.serde.ProtobufDeserializer
InputFormat:            com.twitter.elephantbird.mapred.input.DeprecatedRawMultiInputFormat
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
Compressed:             No
Num Buckets:            -1
Bucket Columns:         []
Sort Columns:           []
Storage Desc Params:
        serialization.class     com.twitter.data.proto.tutorial.AddressBookProtos$AddressBook
        serialization.format    1
Time taken: 0.421 seconds, Fetched: 29 row(s)
```

When I try to select data, it returns no results (doesn't appear to read rows):

```
select count(*) from addresses;

Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=
Starting Job = job_1413311929339_0061, Tracking URL = http://foo:8088/proxy/application_1413311929339_0061/
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1413311929339_0061
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 1
2014-10-28 13:50:37,674 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2014-10-28 13:50:51,055 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 2.14 sec
2014-10-28 13:50:52,152 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 2.14 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 2 seconds 140 msec
Ended Job = job_1413311929339_0061
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Job 0: Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 2.14 sec   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 2 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 2 seconds 140 msec
OK
0
Time taken: 37.519 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

I see the same thing if I create a non-external table or if I explicitly import data into the external table.

Version info for my setup:

```
Thrift 0.7
protobuf: libprotoc 2.5.0
hadoop:
Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.2.0
Subversion http://github.com/cloudera/hadoop -r e1f20a08bde76a33b79df026d00a0c91b2298387
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-10-11T21:00Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 309bccd135b199bdfdd6df5f3f4153d
```

UPDATE:

I see this error in the logs.  My data in HDFS is just raw protobuf (no compression).  I'd like to figure out if that's the issue, and if I can read raw binary protobuf.

```
    Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.(HadoopShimsSecure.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.(MapTask.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:332)
    ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: No codec for file hdfs://foo:8020/user/foo/data/elephantbird/addressbooks/1000AddressBooks-1684394246.bin found
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.mapreduce.input.MultiInputFormat.determineFileFormat(MultiInputFormat.java:176)
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.mapreduce.input.MultiInputFormat.createRecordReader(MultiInputFormat.java:88)
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.mapreduce.input.RawMultiInputFormat.createRecordReader(RawMultiInputFormat.java:36)
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.mapred.input.DeprecatedInputFormatWrapper$RecordReaderWrapper.(DeprecatedInputFormatWrapper.java:256)
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.mapred.input.DeprecatedInputFormatWrapper.getRecordReader(DeprecatedInputFormatWrapper.java:121)
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.mapred.input.DeprecatedFileInputFormatWrapper.getRecordReader(DeprecatedFileInputFormatWrapper.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:65)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you soloved the problem?

I had the same problem just as you described.

Yes you are right, I found out that raw binary protobuf can't be read directly.

This is the problem I had asked.
[Use elephant-bird with hive to read protobuf data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791961/use-elephant-bird-with-hive-to-read-protobuf-data)

Hope it helps

Best regards