# Use elephant-bird with hive to read protobuf data

Tags: hadoop, hive, protocol-buffers, elephantbird

I have a similar problem like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618929/cannot-query-example-addressbook-protobuf-data-in-hive-with-elephant-bird)

The followning are what I used:

1. CDH4.4 (hive 0.10)
2. protobuf-java-.2.4.1.jar
3. elephant-bird-hive-4.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
4. elephant-bird-core-4.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
5. elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
6. The jar file which include the protoc compiled .class file.

And I flow [Protocol Buffer java tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial) create my data "testbook".

And I

use `hdfs dfs -mkdir /protobuf_data` to create HDFS folder.

Use `hdfs dfs -put testbook /protobuf_data` to put "testbook" to HDFS.

Then I follow [elephant-bird web page](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird/wiki/How-to-use-Elephant-Bird-with-Hive) to create table, syntax is like this:

```
create table addressbook
  row format serde "com.twitter.elephantbird.hive.serde.ProtobufDeserializer"
  with serdeproperties (
    "serialization.class"="com.example.tutorial.AddressBookProtos$AddressBook")
  stored as
    inputformat "com.twitter.elephantbird.mapred.input.DeprecatedRawMultiInputFormat"
    OUTPUTFORMAT "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"
  LOCATION '/protobuf_data/';
```

All worked.

But when I submit the query `select * from addressbook;` no result came out.

And I couldn't find any logs with errors to debug.

Could someone help me ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

The problem had been solved.

First I put protobuf binary data directly into HDFS, no result showed.

Because it doesn't work that way.

After asking some senior colleagues, they said protobuf binary data should be written into some kind of container, some file format, like hadoop SequenceFile etc.

The [elephant-bird](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird/wiki/How-to-use-Elephant-Bird-with-Hive#reading-protocol-buffers) page had written the information too, but first I couldn't understand it completely.

After writing protobuf binary data into sequenceFile, I can read the protobuf data with hive.

And because I use sequenceFile format, so I use the create table syntax:

```
inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat'
outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat'
```

Hope it can help others who are new to hadoop, hive, elephant too.

Comment: Oh, and then I bumped into another problem. Although "select * from table_name" works fine. But select column or select(*) would cause some error message like "Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing writable" when it start to run map reduce job. After patch https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird/pull/425. It worked very well.