# Elephant bird with hive to query protobuf file

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, protocol-buffers, elephantbird

I am trying to query **Protobuf** files using **Hive** with **Elephant Bird**. I can create the table, but when I query it nothing happens.

Going through this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791961/use-elephant-bird-with-hive-to-read-protobuf-data), I realized that I need to have to write my `protobufs` into a sequence file.

How do I do it? Do I need to write a separate script in **java** or **python** to do so?